# Sort column names by number

Tags: r

I have 3 differents dataframes. After a `colname(df)` , i have this form of name column for a dataframe :

> Name Length   20  21  22  23  24  25  26
>
> Name Length factor    18  19  20  21  22  23  24
>
> Name Length deep  18  19  20  21  22  23  24  25  26

But I would like to get the largest and smallest element (the numbers are always in the right order but not necessarily in the same position.)

in this example, it would be for the first: 20 , 26
for the second: 18 , 24
and for the third: 18 , 26

I use: `range(colname(df), finite = TRUE)`

but the results is "18" "length"

Any idea?

Comment: it's a data frame but i work only with colname. And yes sorry, it's elements not index. I use range(colname(df)) but the results is "18" "length".

Comment: Please put a [mcve] in your question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can convert the column names to numeric for the selected columns and then take the `range`

```
nm1 <- grep("^\\d+$", names(df1))
range(as.numeric(names(df1)[nm1]))
```

It can be converted to a function

```
f1 <- function(data) {

  nm1 <- grep("^\\d+$", names(data))
  range(as.numeric(names(data)[nm1]))
  }

f1(df1)
f1(df2)
```

---

It can also be directly converted without subsetting the column, but there will be a warning message

```
range(as.numeric(names(df1)), na.rm = TRUE)
```